# How do I get a div that only pops up once?

Tags: video, html, hide

I looked for this and didn't see it already asked, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I have three pages where a div pops up right away, plays a video, and then you can close out of it. I realize it can get annoying if you keep watching the video every time you use the page. I've seen codes to have the video only play on the first visit, but then the div is still there.

Is there any way to have that div only auto-show on the first visit to a page?

Really struggling with this.... Here is the code I have so far.

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
document.onclick = function check(e){ 
    var target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement); 
    var obj = document.getElementById('mydiv'); 
    if(target != obj){
        obj.style.display='none';
        document.getElementById('myvideoelement').pause();


    } 


<div id="mydiv">
<a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();"><img src="images/x2.png" id="x"></a>


    <video id='myvideoelement' autoplay>
        <source src="agoraphobiafinal2.mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a cookie or session containing a bool flag indicating if seen already.
This will be initialized once at startup.

in c#

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
    Session["SeenYet"] = true;
}
```